# Accessing nested JSON with Angular

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to make site with angular.js
I'm having some trouble on displaying data from a Json file like this one:

```
{
"items": [
    {
        "product": {
            "name": "Smartphone1",
            "images": [
                "img1",
                "img2",
                "img3"
            ],
            "price": {
                "value": 3509.10,
                "installments": 10,
                "installmentValue": 389.90
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "product": { 
            "name": "Smart TV",
            "images": [
                "img4",
                "img5",

            ],
            "price": {
                "value": 1139.90,
                "installments": 10,
                "installmentValue": 134.11
            }
        }
    }




]
}
```

My js file is like this: (dont know do this part)

```
angular.module('list', []);
function ListCtrl($scope, $http) {
  $http({
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'data.json'
  }).success(function(data) {
    $scope.items = data.items; 
    $scope.products= [];
    angular.forEach(data.items, function(item, index) {
      angular.forEach(item.product, function(product, index){
        $scope.products.push(product);
      });
    });
  });
}
```

My HTML file is like this: (dont know do this part)

```
<body ng-app="list">
 <div ng-controller="ListCtrl">
    <ul ng-repeat="product in products">
      <li >{{product.id}}</li> 
      <li >{{product.name}}</li> 
      <li >{{product.images1}}</li>
      <li >{{product.images2}}</li>
      <li >{{product.images3}}</li> 
      <li >{{product.price.value}}</li>
      <li >{{product.price.installments}}</li>
      <li >{{product.price.installmentValue}}</li> 
   </ul>
 </div>
```

ty for help guys!
I want to display all products with name, images and price.
Sorry for my code, really dont know angular yet

Answer (score 0):

You can directly push item.product to the products array.

```
app.controller("ListCtrl", ["$scope", "$http",
  function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.products = [];
    $http({
      method: 'GET',
      url: 'data.json'
    }).success(function(data) {
      angular.forEach(data.items, function(item, index) {
        $scope.products.push(item.product);

      });
    });
  }
]);
```

**[DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/dDHmMu1ZirkLgt668d1u?p=preview)**

Comment: i need to display separate

Comment: what do you mean

Comment: <body ng-app="list">
     <div ng-controller="ListCtrl">
       <ul ng-repeat="product in products">
         <li >{{product.id}}</li> 
         <li >{{product.name}}</li> 
         <li >{{product.images1}}</li>
          <li >{{product.images2}}</li> 
         <li >{{product.images3}}</li>  
         <li >{{product.price.value}}</li> 
         <li >{{product.price.installments}}</li> 
         <li >{{product.price.installmentValue}}</li> 
     </ul>

Answer (score 0):

```js
// Code goes here

var app = angular.module("list", []);

app.controller("ListCtrl", function($scope) { 

  $scope.data = {
"items": [
    {
        "product": {
            "name": "Smartphone1",
            "images": [
                "img1",
                "img2",
                "img3"
            ],
            "price": {
                "value": 3509.10,
                "installments": 10,
                "installmentValue": 389.90
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "product": { 
            "name": "Smart TV",
            "images": [
                "img4",
                "img5",

            ],
            "price": {
                "value": 1139.90,
                "installments": 10,
                "installmentValue": 134.11
            }
        }
    }




]
};

});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script data-require="angularjs@1.5.5" data-semver="1.5.5" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.5/angular.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-app="list" ng-controller="ListCtrl">
    <ul ng-repeat="d in data.items">
      <li >{{$index}}</li> 
      <li >{{d.product.name}}</li> 
      <li ng-repeat="imgs in d.product.images" >{{imgs}}</li>
      <li >{{d.product.price.value}}</li>
      <li >{{d.product.price.installments}}</li>
      <li >{{d.product.price.installmentValue}}</li> 
   </ul>
   
  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

You're missing the controlller definition:

```
angular.module('list', []);
function ListCtrl($scope, $http) {
  $http({
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'data.json'
  }).success(function(data) {
    $scope.items = data.items; 
    $scope.products= [];
    angular.forEach(data.items, function(item, index) {
      angular.forEach(item.product, function(product, index){
        $scope.products.push(product);
      });
    });
  });
}
```

Add it after module definition, like this:

```
angular.module('list', [])
.controller('ListCtrl',
function ListCtrl($scope, $http) {
  $http({
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'data.json'
  }).success(function(data) {
    $scope.items = data.items; 
    $scope.products= [];
    angular.forEach(data.items, function(item, index) {
      angular.forEach(item.product, function(product, index){
        $scope.products.push(product);
      });
    });
  });
});
```